# How to remove Falcon application from MacOS?

Tags: macos

To uninstall the Falcon application  one should be able to  use:

```
sudo /Applications/Falcon.app/Contents/Resources/falconctl uninstall
```

However, this does not work, I am getting the error:

```
Error: A maintenance token is required to unload. Specify one with -t
```

I have no idea how to find a maintenance token

Also, I cannot simply move Falcon application to Trash because it is open

I tried to disable Falcon in my MacOs preferences - did not help

Comment: Is this a managed computer? Are you its owner or does it belong to a company? Falcon is corporate endpoint protection - probably only uninstallable by the same authority that installed it.